# Why my computer opens Crytal Reports 8.5 file within about 20 seconds?

Tags: crystal-reports, performance

I have installed Crystal Reports 8.5 on my computer recently.
But When I open an existing file (.rpt), it takes about 20 seconds!

The system O/s is : Win XP SP2.

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware spec?
Report in network location?
No printer installed?
Network printer used by report and either slow or not installed to the PC?
Complex report definition?

There's just way too many things that could cause this. Is this all reports or just one specific report?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, well as you have pointed out, I changed the default printer of my computer from a network printer (p1320) to a local and then try to open that file. Now It seems that there is no delay when opening it. The report file is a local file saved on my computer and before changing the printer, all report files opened within 20 seconds. Well How can I fix this delay when I publish my project?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. My personal experience is that the first report your app loads will take a few seconds to initialise, but after that all reports will load quicker. It's because Crystal has to interrogate the printer driver for information on how to display the report, and network printers seem slower to respond. 20 seconds is huge, though - I've been dealing with a 4 second delay doing this for years.

Comment: Your best bet is probably trying to pre-load the report objects(which I assume is done using CRAXDRT.Application and CRAXDRT.Report) in the background somehow, perhaps during the app's loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

Network printers cause a lot of grief... I like to set my default printer to the XPS Document writer and then when I save the reports I never have an issue with them taking a while to load.